# OpenElec 2.95.5 RPi + XBMC Android remote control

Tags: kodi, remote, android

I'm having problems with my xbmc remote app on android, 
to control openelec running on my RasberryPi.

OpenElec Build: 2.95.5 (seems to be equal to xbmc froyo)

```
Problem:
 - Not listing TV SHOW in main menu
 - Not LIsting Movies in main menu
 - When connecting and On each action this error pops up:
*"http://192.168.1.121:8080/xbmcCmds/xbmcHttp?command=GetSystemInfo(120)"*
```

The only thing that works is the remote control.

Any advise here?

Are there any apps that works with froyo perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, there are 2 options:

```
- Download latest .APK beta of the xbmc remote Here's [a link](https://github.com/tombriden/android-xbmcremote/downloads)! 
- You can use Yatse, which is a great app !!
```

Personal I stick with Yatse until there is a stable official release of the new android xmbc remote app.